# HP 15 laptop does randomly detect wifi drivers and then it doesn't after reboot

Tags: wifi, laptop, hp

I am having trouble with my HP laptop.

I recently installed `pop os` on my HP laptop so I can start practicing Linux. The laptop detects the WiFi signals during install but after I update the `pop os` and reboot the computer, my laptop does not detect any WiFi signals.

Same when Ubuntu detects and connects to my WiFi during install but after I update Ubuntu it also wont detect any WiFi signals, but whats weird is when I reboot my laptop and boots up `pop os` its able to find WiFi signals and works normal, but after I reboot again it wont detect any WiFi signals.

```
$ lspci -knn |grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01) 
DeviceName: Realtek Focus RTL8188EE bgn 1x1 PCI-e HMC WW 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d] 
Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux pop-os 5.3.0-20-generic #21+system76~1572304854~19.10~8caa3e6-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 29 00:4 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Could you add the output of `lspci -knn |grep Net -A3` and `uname -a`.

Comment: ericalvarado@pop-os:~$ lspci -knn |grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
 DeviceName: Realtek Focus RTL8188EE bgn 1x1 PCI-e HMC WW
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
ericalvarado@pop-os:~$ 
]

Comment: ericalvarado@pop-os:~$ uname -a
Linux pop-os 5.3.0-20-generic #21+system76~1572304854~19.10~8caa3e6-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 29 00:4 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu